# How can I create text with a drop shadow combined with a stroke in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography

I want to achieve this text effect. The references below seems a mix of stroke and a box shadow. But the shadow seems *connected* to text (normal text shadow is like basically another *text layer* just below it, displaced slightly).

There are answers here for how to do this in Illustrator and Photoshop but the drop shadows are not combined with strokes. I am not sure how to do it in Photoshop.

[image]
[image]

Kindly note that I don't mean this kind of effect. It's just separated drop shadow.
[image]

Comment: @Scott, is this really a duplicate? I can see how it's related, but this effect is simpler and slightly different. Can be achieved with just drop shadow and stroke.

Comment: @Wolff In my opinion, the *amount* of offset is irrelevant. The technique is the same. *Especially* when you review the Appearance Panel method.

Comment: @Scott can we do it in photoshop? For now I've made piece with Illustrator 3D rotate.

Comment: Well you edited to remove the ask for Illustrator. In Photoshop it's merely a drop shadow and stroke layer style. Added another duplicate link concerning Photoshop.

Comment: @Scott I've edited my question :)

Comment: It's still a duplicate, for *either* application, in my opinion.

Comment: @Scott, this a fundamental thing about this site I don't fully understand (and I might be wrong). When you have two different questions with very similar answers, people tend to call it a duplicate. For example every question where the answer is "use a gradient map" tends to get redirected to the same old question about one specific thing even though the wanted effect might look dramatically different. Can't the same tool be used to achieve (sometimes only slightly) different things? And wouldn't it be more searchable if we keep the variations?

Comment: @Wolff Possibly, but this isn't a "tutorial on demand" site. So, if a technique is described well, there's little benefit to having dozens or hundreds of questions with only *slight* variation to a technique in order to suit a *specific* use case. At least in my opinion.  I mean, to have an Illustrator block shadow question where the *same* technique is detailed except the offset is 15 points rather than 50 points, is hardly beneficial. Not to mention database space.

Comment: To add an example.. Imagine a question at StackOverflow asking how to create an HTML link for an image.. then how to create an HTML link for text... then how to create a red HTML link, then a blue HTMl link, then a green HTML link... it's all the same and it's up to the *user* to show some effort and calculate what they need to alter using the given technique for their specific use case. Yes, the *user* posting a question may feel as if they get more return if *their* question is answered and they don't have to do any work. But again.. this isn't a "tutorial on demand" web site.

Comment: The two duplicates I've linked to above, *clearly* show how to create a block shadow in either Illustrator or Photoshop. If those questions do not provide enough information on the technique, then I'm not opposed to a more detailed, thought out, question regarding some issue which may not be apparent in those duplicates. But at least at that point *some* effort has been shown. As this question stands it's *nothing more* than "how do I do this" with **zero** effort shown.

Comment: Mods reopened it anyway.. so.. there ya go :)

Comment: @Scott I definitely agree there could be more of "what have you tried" in there :)

Comment: @Scott, this is just one question. I'm interested in the principle. I don't really disagree with you at all. In some cases, like this, I just think the "drop shadow with a stroke" look and the "extruded text" look are two different styles you often see. People looking for how to make one might not recognize an answer about the other.

Comment: @Wolff I'll concede, but. "add a stroke" *seems* like common sense, to me anyway, and not worthy of a completely separate question. But.. I'm a grinch apparently. 

Comment: @Scott, on the contrary. You're the Santa of GDSE! 

Comment: @Vikas There is a distortion in the shadow in your first reference that is not in the current answers. You might want to consider if this is also something you're after and make your question more specific.

Comment: @curious yeah I wanted to learn both. I too noticed the same. But wouldn't it be called as 2 questions then? I would like to know both effects. 1st and 2nd references are almost same, but in 1st the black stroke has varying width.

Comment: @Vikas I think it really depends how you word it. If you take some time to describe what you've tried and put words on what you are after, I think one question is fine. Keep in mind that too many questions can be perceived as spam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this could be achieved just by combining two Layer Styles: a stroke effect with a drop shadow effect.  You may have to play around with the thickness of the stroke, and angle of the drop shadow to get it to look right.

I think it's better to do something like this with layer styles because it's non-destructive, and you can edit the text

Anyway here's an example with the settings shown. The font I used was PT Sans Bold.

[image]

Click on the above image to see it larger.

Another method for a sharper look might be to use a 3D extrude on the text. Obviously, this will mean you have to then render the image, and that might not be practical if you don't have enough time.

Here's an example (this is midway through the render)

[image]

The finished result looks quite nice

[image]

Comment: Yeah. It's pretty much same what I wanted to achieve, but I feel the text corners in the reference (THIS SUMMER...) seem sharp. Not sure ho to do it. @user287001 & Billy

Comment: @Vikas, [hard to tell](https://i.imgur.com/sbDB6ui.png).

Comment: @Wolff I mean the bigger text in that image.

Comment: @Vikas - You can adjust the thickness of the stroke, and then the distance, spread, angle, and size of the drop shadow.  It just requires some tweaking. The trick is to make sure the stroke is neither too thick nor too thin, so that it kind of merges into the drop shadow.

Comment: @Vikas, yes, this is from the first "N" in "ANYTHING". None of the upper left corners in "GOALS" are visible. Also look at the "T" in "ANYTHING". Seems to me like the upper left pixel is white here, indicating a round corner. Anyway, it *would* be nice if it was sharp ...

Comment: @Vikas - I've added another approach for a sharper result, using a 3D text extrusion.

Comment: @Wolff we'll discuss it on Sunday.

Comment: @BillyKerr yeah this is what I meant by sharpness :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a drop shadow but made in a different way for the bulged appearance.

Have a text layer. Select the text by Ctrl+Clicking the text object icon in the layers panel. Smooth the selection for ex with Refine edge or like here, apply Select > Modify > Smooth

[image]

Make a new bottom layer and fill the selection there with black or other color. Move the layer a little to get the drop shadow effect:

[image]

Insert layer style "Stroke" to the new layer. Have same color as the fill color and adjust the width:

[image]